# Is there a way to play mpeg videos in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, mpeg

My pc based web application uses HTML5, and I want to import mpeg files to play in my browser which have been saved that way by other application. Is there a way to play these video files with HTML5?

**EDIT:**

The application tries to play the mpeg files from the local hard drive rather than from the server. So, user has an ability to choose the mpeg files to play the selected mpeg files.

HTML:

```
<input id="t20provideoinput" type="file" multiple accept="video/*"/>
<video id="t20provideo" controls controls>
```

Javascript:

```
(function localFileVideoPlayerInit(win) {
    var URL = win.URL || win.webkitURL;
    var sources = [];
    var j = 1;
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
    var videoNode1 = document.querySelector('object');
    var groupElement = document.getElementsByClassName('metric')[0];
    console.log('this is group element ' + groupElement);

    var playSelectedFile = function playSelectedFileInit(event) {
            for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++){
                var file = this.files[i];

                var type = file.type;


                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                sources.push(fileURL);
            }

            groupElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
                videoNode.src = sources[0];
            });
        };

    var inputNode = document.getElementById('t20provideoinput');

    videoNode.addEventListener('ended', function(){
       videoNode.src = sources[j++];
       videoNode.load();
       videoNode.play();
    }, false);

    if (!URL) {
        displayMessage('Your browser is not ' + 
           '<a href="http://caniuse.com/bloburls">supported</a>!', true);

        return;
    }                

    console.log(inputNode);
    if (inputNode != null) { 
        inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false);
    }

}(window));
```

modified from http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/embedded/result,js,html,css/presentation/

I tried few things like adding plugins to the browser, used `Mediaelement.js`, used `object` tag to see if those selected mpeg files can be played. But, the attempts were unsuccessful.

Below is the code snippet where I used the object tag in html5

```
<object type="video/mpeg" data="test.mpeg" width="200" height="40">
  <param name="src" value="test.mpeg" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
  <param name="autoStart" value="0" />
</object>
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: [May be "yes" on some browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), but you'd better use some fallback solution.

Comment: @MattBall. Thanks for posting the link to the article. It was an eye opener. Anyways, I have tried using MediaElement.js but it does not support MPEG video either.I also tried with the object tag. But, it did not work for me either. Please let me know where to head from here.

Answer (score 16):

#### By "mpeg", if you are referring to **[H.264/MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264)**:

---

**UPDATE** (2017, December):

- MP4 is [now supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4) by all major browsers. (IE9+, and all modern desktop and mobile browsers).
- Don't use flash as a fallback anymore, Flash is almost dead.

Other Notes (from caniuse):

- Firefox supports H.264 on Windows 7 and later since version 21.
- Firefox supports H.264 on Linux since version 26 if the appropriate gstreamer plug-ins are installed.
- In Windows 7, the maximum supported resolution is 1920 × 1088 pixels for both software and DXVA decoding. MSDN).
- Chrome has performance problems with long h.264 videos.
- Browsers have trouble with more than one audio track in a video (for multi-language support): IE 11 supports it, Firefox plays the last track, Chrome plays the first track.

---

**Old Answer** *(kept for historical purposes):*

<s>The answer is "not on every browser". Firefox and Opera does not support MP4 within the HTML5 `<video>` tag..</s>

Also, [Google has **announced**](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/01/html-video-codec-support-in-chrome.html) (in 2011) that they will be **removing H.264 support from Chrome**. The reason seems to be Google's [**acquisition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Google_purchase_of_On2) of [**On2 Technologies**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On2_Technologies) and the **[VP8 codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8)**. Which is an equally powerful codec and made [royalty-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royalty-free) by Google after the acquisition. Chrome, Firefox and Opera supports this codec via **[WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM)** which consists of VP8 video and Vorbis audio.

So probably soon enough, **Internet Explorer** and **Safari** will be the only  browsers supporting H.264; which is not a royalty-free codec and **Microsoft** and **Apple** are patent holders!..

So what you can do (for cross-browser support) is;

1. Fall back to [**Adobe Flash** (player)](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/supported-codecs-flash-player.html) when H.264 is not supported.
2. Create multiple encoded versions of your videos including MP4, WebM and Ogg (in order).

Or better, see this example of a fallback mechanism (by [**Kroc Camen**](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)) which combines them all:

***Note 1***: I slightly modified this to add WebM support.
**Note 2**: You should include MP4 at the top, because of an iPad bug that stops the video while searching for the source.

```
<!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- IE / Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.WEBM" type="video/webm" /><!-- Firefox / Chrome / Opera / Android  -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
        <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<!-- you *must* offer a download link as they may be able to play the file locally. customise this bit all you want -->
<p> <strong>Download Video:</strong>
    Closed Format:  <a href="__VIDEO__.MP4">"MP4"</a>
    Open Formats:   <a href="__VIDEO__.WEBM">"WebM"</a>, <a href="__VIDEO__.OGV">"Ogg"</a>
</p>
```

#### By "mpeg", if you are referring to **[MPEG-1 or MPEG-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpeg#Standards)**:

Then No :(

Comment: Yes, I was referring to MPEG-1.

Comment: Still, I think this is the answer to your question.

Comment: does the latest release of firefox (or any updates to browsers since your answer to this in early 2013) effect the code you provided? i ask as i would like to roll this into a php function to use for future sites

Comment: @HollerTrain Did you not click the first link I gave? I'll update this answer soon.

Comment: yes i did. did you realize in 2017 firefox has came out with a huge release since your 2013 answer? if you go here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats - you will see firefox now supports mp4

Comment: Firefox has had support before 2017 (to be specific, 2015). You'd see from the link: https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4 . Anyway, updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's clear that you cannot play mpeg1 or mpeg2 using html5.  I also was looking into something like that.  You could embed a VLC web player that can handle these video formats pretty easily. Maybe consider...  https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

```
<html>
     <title>VLC Mozilla plugin test page</title>
     <body>
          <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
              width="640" height="480" id="vlc">
          </embed>
     <script language="Javascript">
         <!--
         var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
         vlc.audio.toggleMute();
         //!-->
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

For MPEG1, you can try [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg).
JSMpeg is lower latency.

And you can check https://jsmpeg.com/ for pros and cons