# mpg / mpeg audio file duration jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, html5-audio

I have following code base

```
 Audiosource.onloadeddata = function () {
            $("#txtAudioDuration").val(Math.round(Audiosource.duration));
          };
```

When I use .mp3,.mp4,.ogg,.wav audio duration is populated correctly, but when I use mpg or mpeg audio file, the duration is not being loaded.

I have tried with converted mpg and mpeg audio file, I don't have original mpg or mpeg audio files. Is there any link to download these files.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give samples of audio files, that doesn't work? Why do you use video format mpg for audio?

Comment: I found audio is also supported for mpg, and its client requirement.

Comment: Can you provide us with samples?

Comment: http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1316818

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thought was you need to set server content-type headers `audio/mpeg` instead of `video/mpeg`. I tried to configure my `nginx` properly, but audio tag still doesn't work.

You can't do that, browsers [don't support `mpeg` type](http://html5doctor.com/multimedia-troubleshooting/).

> Firefox supports Ogg Vorbis and WAV
>
> Opera supports Ogg Vorbis and WAV
>
> Safari supports MP3, AAC, and MP4
>
> Chrome supports Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV, AAC, and MP4
>
> Internet Explorer 9+ supports MP3, AAC, and MP4
>
> iOS supports MP3, AAC, and MP4
>
> Android supports AAC and MP3

Actually, it can be an old doc, so [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp). But [even wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats), that `mpeg` is not supported by any browser.

Comment: Looks like old docs. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp shows that mp3 is supported. However `mpeg` is not.

Comment: Wiki says the same - no mpeg support - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats

Comment: Isn't it the answer?

Comment: Well, its a observation, not a answer, still accepting as most precise

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [shukshin.ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749836/shukshin-ivan) mpg or mpeg format cannot be embedded in audiosource. Also, here are few links that might be helpful for you in coding  and  with different formats.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

and I found a reference to your question on stackoverflow which is related to importing mpeg files in HTML5 audio tag you can find more detailed explaination:

[Is there a way to play mpeg videos in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929516/is-there-a-way-to-play-mpeg-videos-in-html5)

I hope this helps.